# Remove the first and last names in the foot from the second page

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I am trying to remove the first and last name from the latter page and add a title to it as in the screen shot below.

p.s all data is fake.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm} %Laenge link
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{Alex}
\familyname{Tree}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Steinwasser Weg 22}{54558 Bremen}
\mobile{0176/ 4444 53 451 }
\email{alex.tree@gmail.com}
\photo[3.5cm]{alexsbild}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\clearpage
\recipient{Test Address}{
Nicestr. 30\\67890
Bremen}
\date{\today}
\opening{Sehr geehrter Herr Fischer,}% Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren
\closing{Freundliche Grüße,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle


\begin{justify}
Sie erhalten heute meine Unterlagen zur Initiativbewerbung.



\cvline{}{}{}

Freundliche Grüße, \\
Alex Tree

\end{justify}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot
```

to make the footers in the CV and letter part be equal. Additionally, I've added a `center`ed heading to the `\opening` (with some vertical adjustment):

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual}

\let\makeletterfoot\makecvfoot

\firstname{Who}\familyname{Cares}
\title{A title}
\address{Street Name}{City Name}
\mobile{1-234-567-8901}
\email{first.last@whocares.com}
\photo[3.5cm]{example-image}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\clearpage

\recipient{Test Address}{Street Name \\ City Name}
\date{\today}

\opening{%
\begin{center}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \bfseries Some heading in bold font
\end{center}%
Opening,}

\makelettertitle

Here is some more content.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the sender address in the cover latter as `\recipient{Test Address}{Street Name \\ City Name}`?

Comment: @MrAsker: Could you provide another drawing showing what you mean?